# Why the imagestream spec element generated from oc new-app (source strategy) is empty?

Tags: openshift

In OpenShift 3.11, when I generate a new application using oc-new app from github using "source" strategy an "image stream" object is generated.

But the spec element of that image stream only contains:

```
spec:
 lookupPolicy:
   local: false
```

EDIT----

The spec output of the build config is:

```
spec:
  output:
    to:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: nodeapp:latest
```

But hour after the build finish the image stream spec element remains without tag elements, only the "lookupPolicy" I pasted above.

Why there isn't a "tag" element?
How know this image stream the source docker image it is used for?

In the "status" element there are content pointing to the images, but how is filled the status without a spec?

Thank you.

Comment: When the build finishes, it will be filled out. The target of the image stream which is updated by the build is set by the `spec.output` section of the `BuildConfig`.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I have edited the question to add details taking into account your comment. Still no tag content in the spec of the image stream object